# Class template: add extra variable/method for specific typename

Tags: c++

I have a scenario where class template seems to work for most cases, but some classes will need to define an extra variable/method for specific `typename`. Can I achieve this using templates only or should I use inheritance?

Comment: Lots of things are possible in C++ :) :) Please post a [mcve] to get any constructive feedback.

Comment: let's see if I can come up with an example before the question is closed

Comment: @RSahu I created another question where I explain my scenario in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974842/avoiding-code-duplication-with-templates-and-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a specialization.  I arbitrarily chose `std::vector` as a type for when you wanted special behavior.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    // Stuff for most Types
};

template <typename T, typename A>
struct Foo<std::vector<T, A>>
{
    // Stuff when the type is a std::vector of some types
};
```

Note that any common code will have to be duplicated in the specialization, or you may want to use a base class to represent the implementation - I suggest private inheritance if you choose that route.

Comment: so there is no way to add a field/method to a specialization of a class without copying everything?

Comment: Technically, you aren't "copying everything" - you are making a special case - a specialization - which you define.  Read section 17.7 [temp.spec] of the C++17 spec for more details.

Comment: I created another question where I describe my scenario in more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974842/avoiding-code-duplication-with-templates-and-inheritance