# Avoiding code duplication with templates and inheritance

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a bunch of domain classes that all look similar: they are based on a string value and the same value is repeated a lot, so they all use the same copy-pasted code to intern the underlying value. So I decided to use a template that avoids code duplication:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class InternedString {
 public:
  InternedString(std::string value) {
    //interning the string
  }

  std::size_t hash() {
    //compute hash
  }

  //other methods for constructors and operator overloading
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> interned_value;
};
```

It works well for most domain classes. Types are not interchangeable, which is what I want.

```
struct NameTag{};
typedef InternedString<NameTag> Name;
struct AddressTag{};
typedef InternedString<AddressTag> Address;

Address address = Name("test name"); //doesn't compile, just like I want
```

Couple of other domain classes don't fit into this template. They require additional constructor field and different definition of some methods. So it looks like inheritance is the way to go here:

```
struct CompanyTag{};
class Company : InternedString<CompanyTag> {
 public:
  Company(int id, const std::string& value) : InternedString(value), id(id) {}

  //override hash method
 private:
  int id;
};
```

Several questions that I have:

- can (should) this functionality be achieved with just templates?
- since I use inheritance should I remove the template parameter then and just define subclasses for `Name` and `Address`?
- I am not a fan of inheritance, because it is often misused. Does the current scenario justify use of inheritance?

Comment: Note that your use of inheritance here is PRIVATE inheritance, which is similar to composition and does not have the same issues as public inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. I actually need to expose inherited methods as if they were defined in subclasses, so I have to use public inheritance.

Comment: No - you do not have to use public inheritance, and I would urge you to not do so.  It will bring you all kinds of pain unless you completely redesign stuff for that case.  These are simply type wrappers, and do not fit that mold.  I'd suggest leaving them as they are - and when you want a special one, like Company - specialize it on the CompanyTag, with private inheritance from a InternedString<detail::CompanyBaseTag> which is used just to get access to the base functionality.

Comment: @JodyHagins so you are suggesting to keep typedef for classes that don't need specialization and use private inheritance for other cases? The problem with this approach is that there are 10 methods (mostly constructors and overloaded operators) that I would have to explicitly define in every subclass to proxy to base class.

Comment: I hacked up my thoughts in an answer since it was more than would fit in a comment.  You don't redefine them all - just "using" declare the ones you want public - and there really shouldn't be many if you indeed want them that way.  Anyway, there are lots of ways to do this - but I would again not suggest inheritance unless you are ready to make the base class have a virtual destructor and go the whole dynamic polymorphism route.  INHERITANCE IS NOT CODE REUSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think inherticance is justfied here. However, I would change the definition of `Name` and `Address` to keep their definitions consistent with `Company`.

```
struct NameTag{};
struct Name : InternedString<NameTag>
{
   using InternedString<NameTag>::InternedString;
};

struct AddressTag{};
struct Address : InternedString<AddressTag> 
{
   using InternedString<AddressTag>::InternedString;
};
```

The `using` directives in the classes cause the base class constructors to be brought into the scope of the derived classes and allow one to use:

```
Name n("A name");
Address a("An Address");
```

Comment: why do you think I should keep the template parameter since we define all the classes as subclasses? any reason you used `struct` instead of `class`?

Comment: @damluar, good call. `InternedString` can be regular class, not a class template. I used `struct` for simplicity in SO.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use public inheritance here?  It brings all kinds of issues to the table - though private inheritance means that you need to expose the parts that you want as public.

Comment: Yes, because otherwise it would be a lot of boiler plate in each subclass to define those methods and call super() or whatever the syntax in C++ is

Comment: @RSahu I actually have to keep templates. I have methods like `InternedString(const InternedString&)` and `bool operator==(const InternedString& rhs)` in base class. If I removed the template parameter, it will become possible to copy Name from Address and compare them with ==, right?

Comment: @damluar, No, you still can't  assign a `Name` to an `Address` and vice-versa, or compare them.

Comment: Comparison does seem to work, while copying does not: https://onlinegdb.com/BkgZqvzDL

Comment: @damluar,  I think you know the bits and pieces well enough to make an informed decision :) :)

Comment: I just don't know c++ lol. Why the hell does == work, while copying fails?

Comment: @damluar - Do not forget `struct D : Base` is the same as `struct D : public Base` and `class D : Base` is the same as `class D : private Base`.

Comment: @damluar, that's because `operator==` is inherited while `operator=` is not. The assignment operator is compiler generated unless a class defines its own.

Comment: @damluar, if you want to get deep into C++, it will be worth your while to pay a visit to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/special.

Comment: my brain is overloaded. Last question, if `operator==` is inherited, it does mean that I can compare apples and oranges which I don't want. So it looks like I do need template parameter to make these classes independent so to say.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of like the example I was describing using a specialization.

There are issues, but it avoids the issues of inheritance, and it keeps all of your interned-string classes the same.

Imagine an interface that takes any interned string - maybe for streaming...

```cpp
template <typename CharT, typename TraitsT, typename TagT>
auto &
operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT> &strm,
    InternedString<TagT> const &s)
{
    return strm << s.str();
}
```

Or, imagine if you wanted a trait like this...

```cpp
template <typename T> struct IsInternedString : std::false_type { };
template <typename T> struct IsInternedString<InternedString<T>> : std::true_type { };
```

Having a bunch of specialized classes that act kinda like one of those brings difficulties, while making a specialization still allows all of the generic InternedString stuff to work in a generic way.

For example...

```cpp
namespace detail {
struct CompanyTag { };
}

struct CompanyTag { };
template<>
class InternedString<CompanyTag> : InternedString<detail::CompanyTag>
{
    using IS = InternedString<detail::CompanyTag>;

public:
    Company(int id, const std::string& value)
    : IS(value)
    , id(id)
    { }

    // Expose the stuff you want public from the private base
    using IS::foo;
    using IS::bar;

    // You want to redefine hash - not override a virtual because the
    // hash from the base class is neither virtual nor visible to anyone
    std::size_t hash()
    {
        return combine_hash(IS::hash(), hash_for(id));
    }

    // Other stuff specific to Company...

private:
    int id;
};
using Company = InternedString<CompanyTag>;
```

Just something to think about, in the real of your entire system design and implementation.

Comment: I am trying to understand what's going on here. We are inheriting from an instance of a template, but at the same time creating a specialization of that same template. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but remember a template is just that - a template - it is nothing more.  So, InternedString<CompanyTag> privately inherits from InternedString<detail::CompanyTag> - which is a totally different type, but it has all the stuff that any instantiation of the primary template would have.  The inheritance is private, so the base class is not visible, and it is similar to composition - except all the stuff is available to the derived class - and the derived class can choose to expose any part of the API it wants.  A specialization only has what it defines - inheritance brings the standard stuff.